# How do I take the value of a String var without taking the quotes?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an sql script that defines some values and then calls the insert statement with those values. The thing is when it takes the value out of the vars the quotes goes away, I think as expected... But I need to use that value as a parameter for the insert so I need those quotes to stay.

```
-- Item id
def ITM_ID = 1
-- Item description
def ITM_DE = "Logic Brake Shoes"

INSERT INTO item (ITM_ID, ITM_DE) VALUES (&ITM_ID, &ITM_DE);
```

This is being interpreted as it follows with an error after Logic because of the space:

```
insert into item(ITM_ID, ITM_DE) values (1, Logic Brake Shoes)
```

Someone knows how do I take the value as a literal? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just enclose the `&ITM_DE` variable in apostrophes and it will work:

```
INSERT INTO item (ITM_ID, ITM_DE) VALUES (&ITM_ID, '&ITM_DE');

old l: INSERT INTO item (ITM_ID, ITM_DE) VALUES (&ITM_ID, '&ITM_DE')
new l: INSERT INTO item (ITM_ID, ITM_DE) VALUES (1, 'Logic Brake Shoes')

1 row created.
```